# Using a helper function in Java to get an index in an array (no parameters)

Tags: java

```
public int posOfFinalNineFromEnd () {
return posHelper (first);
}
private static int posHelper(Node i) {
int result = posHelper(i.next);
if (result >= 0) { 
    return result;
}
if (i.item == 9.0) {
    return result+1;
}
return result-1;
}
```

Firstly, I know this code is a mess. Please go easy on me. I'm very new to Java. This is throwing me various errors. The point is I need to find the index the final 9 in a given list (i.e. 0,1,9,2,9 would call 4). If 9.0 is the last index, return 0. And if there is no 9, call a -1.

I also need to use backward recursion. I'm just beyond lost. I also can't use other functions like contains() or to simply fill the given parameters.

I was able to solve it, to an extent without the recursion. That is below

```
    if(first != null) {
    int index = 0;
    int indexTemp = 0;          

    for (Node x = this.first; x != null; x=x.next) {
        if (x.item == 5.0)
            indexTemp = index;
        index++;
    }
    index -= 1;

    if (this.first.item == 5.0)
        return index;

    if (indexTemp == 0)
        return -1;

    return index - indexTemp; 
}
return -1;
```

}

However, this code messes up, in that it doesn't return -1 if there's no 9. Everything else works. But, I'm trying to basically combine the two and fix this...

Comment: Must `posHelper()` only receive a Node?  Can we change that to `postHelp(Node i, int index)`?  Your title says "no parameters" but `posHelper()` clearly is already receiving a parameter of type Node.  Or was the "no parameters" only for `posOfFinalNineFromEnd()`?

Comment: Helper can receive more than a Node. So, yes, that would work. There just can't be anything changed about the first line. Can you please show me what it'd look like?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it...

```
public int posOfFinalNineFromEnd()
{
    return posHelper(first, 0);
}

private int posHelper(Node i, int index)
{
    if (i == null)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        int result = posHelper(i.next, index+1);
        return (result == -1) ? ((i.item == 9.0) ? index : -1) : result;
    }
}
```

Sure...here's an expanded version along with my entire testing code:

```
public class Node
{

    public float item;
    public Node next = null;
    
    public Node(){}

    public Node(float value)
    {
        item = value;
    }
    
    public Node add(float value)
    {
        next = new Node(value);
        return next;
    }    
    
}

public class LinkedList
{
    
    public Node first;
    
    public LinkedList() {}
    
    public static void main()
    {
        LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
        list.first = new Node(0);
        list.first.add(1).add(9).add(2).add(9);
        
        System.out.println("List contents:");
        Node n = list.first;
        while(n != null)
        {
            System.out.println(n.item);
            n = n.next;
        }
        
        int lastNine = list.posOfFinalNineFromEnd();
        System.out.println("Position of last nine: " + lastNine);
    }
    
    public int posOfFinalNineFromEnd()
    {
        if (first != null)
            return posHelper(first, 0);
        else
            return -1;
    }
    
    private int posHelper(Node i, int index)
    {
        if (i == null)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            int result = posHelper(i.next, index+1);
            if (result == -1)
            {
                if (i.item == 9.0)
                {
                    return index;
                }
                else
                {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: What is the question mark in the last line? Is there any way to simplify that? I ran this code as is and it did not work.

Comment: That's a [ternary statement](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/ternary-operator.html#:~:text=The%20Java%20ternary%20operator%20functions,if%20the%20condition%20is%20false%20.).  It's shorthand for an `if/else` block.

Comment: Is there any way you can re-write it as an if and else so I can sort of understand it?